# Flattened view for multi-role permission system

Tags: postgresql, permissions, view, role

I'm currently working on a multi-role permission system for one of my projects, my database (postgres) tables are setup like this:

**user**

- id
- username
- email
- …

**user_role**

- id
- user_id
- role_id

**role**

- id
- name

**permission**

- id
- name

**role_permission**

- id
- role_id
- permission_id
- allowed (nullable bool)

For my backend I need a view table now which contains a "flattened" permission set for each user with the following columns:

- user_id
- permission_name
- permission_allowed

now the part I struggle badly with is that I need the following rules be applied:

- role id 1 should act as starting point, the "default" permissions
- then all allowed = true results of each assigned role to the user (except role id 1) should overwrite the permissions of the results
- then all allowed = false results of each assigned role to the user (except role id 1) should overwrite the permissions of the results

without having duplicate permission names. Basically how a firewall works (deny > allow).

I've already tinkered with UNION's and bool_and/bool_or aggregations, but I don't think that this is the correct solution, as I want the allowed column of each query result sequentially overridden.

Any ideas are welcome.

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dCLRKXr7HwpZgKBSN99jXn/0

Example output (unrelated to the fiddle content):

| user_id | permission_name | permission_allowed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | can_login | false |
| 1 | can_change_email | true |
| 1 | can_change_password | true |
| 1 | can_post | true |
| 2 | can_login | true |
| 2 | can_change_email | true |
| 2 | can_change_password | false |
| 2 | can_post | true |
| 3 | can_login | true |
| 3 | can_change_email | false |
| 3 | can_change_password | true |
| 3 | can_post | true |

p.s. I would gladly donate some crypto for help if this is allowed.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the desired output given an input? Its not clear from your description or the data in the fiddle what the intended result is.

Comment: Sure, I've updated my question with some example output.

Comment: As a side note: many:many join tables such as `user_role` and `role_permission` do not need a `id` column. They should have a composite primary key made up of the two foreign key columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script should get you all the user permissions using the desire logic

```
SELECT
  u.id,
  p.name,
  COALESCE(BOOL_AND(CASE WHEN rp.role_id > 1 THEN rp.allowed END),
           BOOL_AND(CASE WHEN rp.role_id = 1 THEN rp.allowed END)) AS permission_allowed
FROM "user" u
LEFT JOIN user_role ur ON ur.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN role_permission rp ON (rp.role_id = ur.role_id OR rp.role_id = 1)
LEFT JOIN "permission" p on p.id = rp.permission_id
GROUP BY
  u.id,
  p.id,
  p.name;
```

- We simply join all users with their roles (as well as the default role), and with the permissions for those roles.
- Then we group by user ID and permission ID, and take the `BOOL_AND` of `allowed` (ie `false` if available otherwise `true`) for each permission, using the default role if any other is not available.

[**DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oY47rh3Lz3LjbZnSdPw8Rq/0)

Comment: That seems to do the trick, thank you very much. Please drop me a wallet address, I would love to buy you a coffee.